# Update WooCommerce billing_phone with custom meta value in user_register hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On user registration from another plugin, I'm trying to update the WooCommerce 'billing_phone' value with a custom meta value from that plugin. Like this:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'eks_user_register_phone' );

function eks_user_register_phone( $user_id ) {

    $full_phone = get_user_meta($user_id, 'custom_phone_value', true);
   
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_phone', $full_phone);

}
```

At the time this is fired I do have access to other values such as  'nickname':

```
$get_nick = get_user_meta($user_id, 'nickname', true);
```

Which would reflect this as mentioned in the Wordpress codex: [Plugin API/Action Reference/user_register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)

> Not all user meta data has been stored in the database when this
> action is triggered.

Is there a way to solve this using this particular hook?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you use the wrong user meta key for the phone number. If I remember correct the default key is 'phone_number', or is it a custom meta field?

Comment: It's a custom meta field called 'custom_phone_value'. Created by the other plugin.

Comment: What for plug-in is it? I think your hook on user_register triggers before the hook of the plug-in. You can read the documentation of the plug-in on how it's adding the user meta or you can dig through the code of the plug-in and hook it after the insert of the user meta.

Comment: It's 'Digits'. I can't see that it's hookable, or possibly I cant work out how it is. This is why I was trying using the user_register action hook. At the moment my changes are hard coded in the plugin.

Comment: Do you have a plug-in URL? So that I can look at the source code?

Comment: Yes I created a Gist, lines 369-381. That does what I was looking for, but hard-coded as mentioned. https://gist.github.com/Evakos/1d40968d47d22742682ace52be660091

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 conditions:

1. User registration
2. The custom meta value availability.

So, you can just try to find a hook inside the plugin, which is called before/after the metadata has been processed, and attach a function to it inside "user_register".

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myfunction_user_register' );
function myfunction_user_register() {
    add_action( 'custom_plugin_meta_added', 'myfunction_next' );
}
function myfunction_next() {
    //your code
}
```

Another solution is to use the very latest hook, like 'shutdown'.

Also, please note helpful WC hook: 'woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta'